# ModalPopupExtender problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I had :ModalPopupExtender which display when user didnot register .And when user login it didnot display but some browsers as firefox or safarie :ModalPopupExtender  apear and hiden .I tried to add :ModalPopupExtender  in updatepanel but i didnot so please how can I do to solve this issue.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["RegisteredUser"] == null)
        {
            pnlModal_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
        }
        else
        {

            Result.Visible = true;
            Result.Text = string.Format("Welcom {0}", Session.Contents["RegisteredUser"]);


        }
```

}

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlModal" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
                        Our Valued Customer You Are Not Registered Are You Want To Register?
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <table id="LoginTL" runat="server" width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0"
                            cellspacing="2" style="border-color: #666666">
                            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                                <td id="Td1" width="80px" class="bod_d_reg_txt_p lm7" runat="server">
                                    Username :
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                                    <label>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtUser" runat="server" Width="125px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td3" runat="server">
                                    <table width="110" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <label>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CBRemeber" runat="server" class="tx_s" />
                                                </label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="bod_d_reg_txt_w">
                                                Remember me
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                                <td id="Td4" width="80" class="bod_d_reg_txt_p lm7" runat="server">
                                    Password :
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td5" runat="server">
                                    <label>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TXTPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="125px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td6" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="IBLogin" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/home-d_login.jpg" OnClick="IBLogin_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                                <td id="Td7" runat="server">
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td8" runat="server">
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td9" runat="server">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="Tr4" runat="server">
                                <td id="Td10" runat="server">
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td11" runat="server">
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td12" runat="server">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="Tr5" runat="server">
                                <td id="Td13" runat="server">
                                    <a href="Default.aspx" id="btnClose" runat="server">Close</a>
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td14" runat="server">
                                </td>
                                <td id="Td15" runat="server">
                                    <a href="Registeration.aspx" id="Register" runat="server">Register</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br />
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID="btnYes" ID="pnlModal_ModalPopupExtender"
                        runat="server" Enabled="True" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="pnlModal"
                        CancelControlID="btnYes" DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="">
                    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="btnYes" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this property to panel and it worked well
Style="display: none"